# Error in send push notifications programmatically using java code in One Signal to android app

Tags: java, android, push-notification, onesignal

I have try the below code from One Signal documentation to send push notifications to mobile. But somehow it failed and throw exception.The relevant API key has been changed. I try to debug on Android studio and the error exist at " `OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();`" , is that possible i can customize the push notifications programmatically using these java code, Please advise.

```
try {
String jsonResponse;



URL url = new URL("https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
   HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
   con.setUseCaches(false);
   con.setDoOutput(true);
   con.setDoInput(true);

   con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
   con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic NGEwMGZmMjItY2NkNy0xMWUzLTk5ZDUtMDAwYzI5NDBlNjJj");
   con.setRequestMethod("POST");

   String strJsonBody = "{"
                      +   "\"app_id\": \"5eb5a37e-b458-11e3-ac11-000c2940e62c\","
                      +   "\"included_segments\": [\"All\"],"
                      +   "\"data\": {\"foo\": \"bar\"},"
                      +   "\"contents\": {\"en\": \"English Message\"}"
                      + "}";


   System.out.println("strJsonBody:\n" + strJsonBody);

   byte[] sendBytes = strJsonBody.getBytes("UTF-8");
   con.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(sendBytes.length);

   OutputStream outputStream = con.getOutputStream();
   outputStream.write(sendBytes);

   int httpResponse = con.getResponseCode();
   System.out.println("httpResponse: " + httpResponse);

   if (  httpResponse >= HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK
      && httpResponse < HttpURLConnection.HTTP_BAD_REQUEST) {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getInputStream(), "UTF-8");
      jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
      scanner.close();
   }
   else {
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(con.getErrorStream(), "UTF-8");
      jsonResponse = scanner.useDelimiter("\\A").hasNext() ? scanner.next() : "";
      scanner.close();
   }
   System.out.println("jsonResponse:\n" + jsonResponse);

   } catch(Throwable t) {
   t.printStackTrace();
   }
```

Comment: Kindly update the question with exception stack trace

Comment: I have place a debug on the t.printStackTrace(); and it show "NetworkOnMainThreadException"

Comment: NetworkOnMainThreadException - has nothing to do with onesignal. This exception is thrown when an application attempts to perform a networking operation on its main thread. Try using AsyncTask.